# Unable to get Maya's workspaceControl window geometry in closeEvent

Tags: python, qt, maya, pyside2

I've been using an adaptation of the [this](https://gist.github.com/liorbenhorin/69da10ec6f22c6d7b92deefdb4a4f475) wrapper in Maya, so that I can parent a Qt window to `workspaceControl`, which makes it dockable with different parts of the user interface. Basically it creates an empty dockable window using Maya's own code, gets the C++ pointer to it, and wraps the Qt window inside of that window.

The version linked does not handle `closeEvents` correctly, so I adapted it so it'll always trigger upon closing down. I did this by setting `Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose` as an attribute on the Qt window and linking the `destroyed` signal to `close()`.

However, I found that the functions like `geometry`, `width`, `move`, etc, don't work properly as the window is in multiple levels of parents. In fact, to get any of those values, you need to call `self.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().func()`. The issue arises when the window is closed, as it seems to delete the higher level parents before `closeEvent` is called, resulting in an error since `self.parent().parent()` returns `None` after that.

I would like to be able to save the window position on exit, but can't figure out how to get access to the information before it's deleted. Other than just recording it each time any function is run, is there a way I could cleanly do it at the end?

Here's the most trimmed down example I could come up with:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from shiboken2 import wrapInstance
import maya.OpenMayaUI as omUI
import pymel.core as pm

def dockable_window(window_class):
    main_control = pm.workspaceControl(window_class.ID)
    win_ptr = omUI.MQtUtil.findControl(window_class.ID)
    control_wrap = wrapInstance(int(win_ptr), QtWidgets.QWidget)
    control_wrap.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
    win = window_class(control_wrap)
    control_wrap.destroyed.connect(win.close)

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    ID = 'testing'
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        #Create a button that will show the geometry when clicked
        b = QtWidgets.QPushButton('test')
        b.clicked.connect(self.show_actual_geometry)
        parent.layout().addWidget(b)

    def show_actual_geometry(self):
        """This will work until it is called during closeEvent."""
        print self.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().geometry()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print self.show_actual_geometry()
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.closeEvent(self, event)

dockable_window(MyWindow)
```

Comment: The workspaceControl offers a closeCommand. Maybe this could be a way to save the position and size.

Comment: I haven't ever managed to get that working. Every function I've tried just results in `SyntaxError: invalid syntax #`, because it tries to call an empty MEL function for some reason.

Comment: Ah, okay. Even if I do not get a syntax error, the workspaceControl does not behave as expected because it is not closed if you hit the close button. It is only hidden. You can use the visibleChangeCommand which is called if the visibility state changes.

Comment: So your problem could be that maya does not close and destroy the workspaceControl, but only hides it.

Comment: No, I was wrong, the window is closed, only the close command is not called.

Comment: Oh damn, you may have actually solved it. `visibleChangeCommand` is called just before the widget is destroyed and let me access the position. Just gotta try it on the main class now :)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to report back after finishing for the day, it did actually work. Using the above example as an example lol, I added the line `pm.workspaceControl(window_class.ID, edit=True, visibleChangeCommand=win.show_actual_geometry)` next to the destroyed connection. It calls at other points too so can't be connected to `closeEvent`, but for saving it appears to work fine. If you drop it in an answer I'll mark it as solved, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workspaceControl seems not to close and destroy it's widget correctly, at least the close event is not called. For that reason the closeCommand does got called even if the retain attribute ist set to false (tried in Maya2018). A workaround is to use the visibleChangeCommand. It gets called if the close button is clicked.